# Wait for Firebase to completely load in Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise

I have an issue where i want fire a method from a service immediately after a route change. That method has to lookup an object on a Firebase:

```
 app.service('document',function($q,$firebase){

    var databaseReference   = new Firebase(firebase),
        database            = $firebase(databaseReference);

            return{

                getDocument: function(title){

                    return database.documents[title];
                }

            }
    });
```

unfortunately, the `documents` property won't load directly; it takes a few ms to appear.

I know that i could wrap this up in a promise, but how can i make the service being returned only when that promise is resolved?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Angular ui-router, you can put one or more promises in a `resolve` block of the same state your controller is in, and declare those as dependencies to be injected into your controller. The controller then does not get created until all those promises have been resolved, and within your controller you'll have access to the resolved promises.  See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve for more info.